# Does uninstall.php in Wordpress Plugin work on localhost?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, uninstallation

WP codex says that uninstall.php in root folder is called when user deletes the plugin. My solution does not work, so I wonder if it works on localhost, because there are some wp features not working on localhost.

My code:

```
if (!defined('WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN')) {
    die;
}

global $wpdb;

$wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ".WP_CONFIG_TABLE);
$wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ".WP_SUBJECTS_TABLE);
$wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ".WP_EVENTS_TABLE);
$wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ".WP_STUDENTS_TABLE);
```

All Tables are defined above, that is not the issue.

Comment: Yes, It will work on localhost too.

Comment: Yes on localhost its working fine

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with permissions, but after

```
chmod -R 777 wordpress
```

it works just fine